# Masked array, per-item operations and processing power

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

1) I was wondering if in a operation with a masked array, operations occur on masked values in per-item operations (adding one, etc), or are they left intact?

if original values are

```
 nparray=[1,2,3,4]
 mask=ma.masked_array(nparray, mask=[-1]
 >>>mask [1,2,3,--]
```

will mask+1 be

```
>>>[2,3,4,--]
```

with -- as 5 or 4 (if it could be revealed?*)?

2) I have the same question with iterators and enumerators, as
I tested and saw that indexes are conserved, but I don't know if values are processed or merely skipped, or if even masked indexes are skipped?

3)*Is there a mean to suppress the mask then, I can't find it there:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html

My guess is that indexes are processed and not skipped, but that values are.
4) Is it an efficient way to avoid useless processing of values you don't want to be processed or are there better ways in terms of speed?

5) If I modify incrementally the mask as it is iterated upon, will this cause some kind of exception? In Java, it did, but I am only a beginner in Python.

Comment: why can't you just check it?

Comment: That's valid for 1 and 2, but for 3-5, I can't really ('I said exceptions, but there could be invisible problems). Also, I had not access to python at the time I was thinking about my algorithm.

Comment: You didn't have 3-5 when I wrote that comment, anyway, you have some good answers now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Masking is a convenient way of handling Nan like values that you don't want to propagate through operations like `sum` and `mean`.  It does not speed up calculations.  As far as I know it is written in Python/numpy without any extra compiled code.

Consider these 2 time tests.  One just adds a 1 to all elements of an array.  The slower one constructs a masked array (with all values masked).  In a sense it 'skips' all elements - but it is a lot slower.

```
In [614]: %%timeit m=np.arange(1000)
   .....: m += 1
   .....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.48 µs per loop
In [615]: %%timeit m=np.ma.masked_array(np.arange(1000),mask=[True])
m += 1
   .....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.4 µs per loop
```

Setting `mask=[False]` takes the same (slow) time.

Boolean indexing is a good way skipping values.  But even that does not speed things up:

```
In [624]: %%timeit m=np.arange(1000)                              
m[m<500] += 1
   .....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.5 µs per loop
```

The time penalty from using a basic slice indexing isn't as great

```
In [628]: %%timeit m=np.arange(1000)
m[:500] += 1
   .....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.2 µs per loop
```

`numpy` does things like simple addition with compiled code.  Steps like indexing and masking, even when using compile code themselves, still add processing time.  There are good reasons for selectively processing elements of arrays, but saving time on simple calculations is not one of them.

Comment: Very useful insights, thanks a lot. My problem is that I have to process an array to select its elements by iteration, the problem being that the array length might be enormous with numbers with 10 digits or more, and It think 90% of "useless" numbers that I might want to avoid using in operations. The problem is that I need a constant index in parallel, but a dictionnary would perform much less fast. I thought of using an ndarray but actually, I need values of different types so I guess I am stuck with this (or maybe using two arrays in parallel?)

Answer (score 2):

Performing `MaskedArray += 1` does not change the masked value. You can access the full data array by using [`MaskedArray.data`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray.data) to check this:

```
In [26]: mymask
Out[26]: 
masked_array(data = [1 2 3 --],
             mask = [False False False  True],
       fill_value = 999999)

In [27]: mymask.data
Out[27]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [28]: mymask+=1

In [29]: mymask
Out[29]: 
masked_array(data = [2 3 4 --],
             mask = [False False False  True],
       fill_value = 999999)

In [30]: mymask.data
Out[30]: array([2, 3, 4, 4])
```

**EDIT:** 
As pointed out by @JoeKington in comments, there are some operations that will modify the masked data, for example `np.add(mymask, 1, mymask)`, so its best not to assume that the masked data will not be modified.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are cases where the masked data is changed.  `mymask += 1` won't modify the masked data, but `np.add(mymask, 1, mymask)` will. It's best not to rely on the masked portion not being changed.

Comment: Nice addition, I will look for this too.

Comment: Thanks @JoeKington, I've added that info to my answer